# Maven fails dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I cant understand, why is failing this dependency in  my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>statistics</groupId>
            <artifactId>statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

But I have got the root well done:

C:\m2\repository\statistics\statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT\1.0

Any help??

Im working of course in mode offline.

Comment: The error is the following Missing artifact statistics:statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT:jar:1.0

Comment: When I googled it, I found this: `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.terracotta.internal</groupId>
  <artifactId>statistics</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Stills fails, trying to understand why the dependency is not found

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency looks weird with the duplicate versionreference. Maven is looking for `${localrepository}/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.type`, where the dots in the groupId (if any) are used as directory-separators.
So in you case Maven is looking for `C:\m2\repository\statistics\statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT\1.0\statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT-1.0.jar`.
However, what you probably want is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>statistics</groupId>
        <artifactId>statistics</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>statistics</groupId>
        <artifactId>statistics</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>  and the new root is C:\m2\repository\statistics\statistics-1.0-SNAPSHOT\1.0          ///however stills fails